# Есть ли способ закрасить фоном не меняя структуры?

Tags: css

Сверстал меню для сайта ... но в макете выглядит так :

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

а получилось так :

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

есть ли способ, закрасить фоном без изменения структуры html ?

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  width: 600px;
}

ul:first-child {
  padding: 10px 0;
  background: lightblue;
}

ul:first-child li {
  position: relative;
}

ul>li>ul {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 250px;
  height: 140px;
  background: #fbfbfb;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: all .7s linear .5s;
  opacity: 0;
}

ul>li>ul li {
  padding: 4px 0;
}

ul>li>ul li a {
  font-size: 14px;
}

ul li:hover ul {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="">Пункт 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Пункт 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Пункт 3</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">Пункт 3-1</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Пункт 3-2</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Пункт 3-3</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Пункт 3-4</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Пункт 3-5</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Пункт 3-6</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Пункт 3-7</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Пункт 3-8</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Пункт 3-9</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Пункт 3-10</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Пункт 3-11</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Пункт 3-12</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="">Пункт 4</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Пункт 5</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: А вам принциписально макет менять нельзя?

Comment: заказчик барин ... сказано так значит так ... не могу менять html ...знаю это тупо но ...

Comment: Так и рождаются костыли. кхм кхм, а можно задавать классы?

Comment: @Duoxx  думаю да ... это не оговаривалось по крайней мере ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот мой вариант тут у списка коричневый фон но у первых 5 элементов фон белый

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  width: 600px;
}

ul:first-child {
  padding: 10px 0;
  background: lightblue;
}

ul:first-child li {
  position: relative;
}

ul>li>ul {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 250px;
  max-height: 140px;
  background: #BCBC9C;

  margin-top: 10px;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: all .7s linear .5s;
  opacity: 0;
}

ul>li>ul li {
    padding: 4px;
}



ul>li>ul li a {
  font-size: 14px;
}
ul>li>ul>li:nth-child(-n+5) {
  background:#fff;
}

ul>li>ul>li:nth-child(1n+6) a{
  color:#fff;

}



ul li:hover ul {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="">Пункт 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Пункт 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Пункт 3</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">Пункт 3-1</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Пункт 3-2</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Пункт 3-3</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Пункт 3-4</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Пункт 3-5</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Пункт 3-6</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Пункт 3-7</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Пункт 3-8</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Пункт 3-9</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Пункт 3-10</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Пункт 3-11</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Пункт 3-12</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="">Пункт 4</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Пункт 5</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: я так понял фон не ul  а li ?

Comment: у списка коричневый фон но у первых 5 элементов фон белый

Answer (score 1):

Изобрел супер топорный метод , но жду дельного примера более лучшего чем мой  :

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  width: 600px;
}

ul:first-child {
  padding: 10px 0;
  background: lightblue;
}

ul:first-child li {
  position: relative;
}

ul>li>ul {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 250px;
  height: 140px;
  background: #fbfbfb;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: all .7s linear .5s;
  opacity: 0;
}

ul>li>ul li {
  padding: 4px 0;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 100;
}

ul>li>ul li a {
  font-size: 14px;
}

ul li:hover ul {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

ul>li>ul:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 190px;
  height: 160px;
  background:#BCBC9C;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 0;
}

ul>li>ul li:not(.elem) a {
  color: #fbfbfb;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="">Пункт 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Пункт 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Пункт 3</a>
    <ul>
      <li class="elem"><a href="">Пункт 3-1</a></li>
      <li class="elem"><a href="">Пункт 3-2</a></li>
      <li class="elem"><a href="">Пункт 3-3</a></li>
      <li class="elem"><a href="">Пункт 3-4</a></li>
      <li class="elem"><a href="">Пункт 3-5</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Пункт 3-6</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Пункт 3-7</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Пункт 3-8</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Пункт 3-9</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Пункт 3-10</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Пункт 3-11</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Пункт 3-12</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="">Пункт 4</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Пункт 5</a></li>
</ul>
```